Как передать музыку на bluetooth колонку с linux-устройства, используя средства C/C++?
Есть задача написать управление блютуз-колонкой под линукс(raspberry pi). Колонка должна проигрывать музыку и по команде с монитора переключать её. Изучив вопрос, пришел к следующему порядку действий:

Нужно по шестибайтному адресу найти нужное устройство
Запросить у устройства службы и характеристики
Произвести запись в соответствующую службу по её uuid

(Основные источники тут и тут, хотя конечно отсмотрел я куда больше материала и по другим источникам). Естественно я так же посмотрел как это устроено в linux (тут и тут).
Немного изучив вопрос пришел к выводу, что делать всё с нуля будет слишком долго и нашел несколько готовых библиотек(как пример эта или эта).
Используя эти библиотеки, без всяких проблем мне удалось пройти по первым двум пунктам, а вот с третьим возникает проблема. Из того что я вижу, обе данные библиотеки предлагают побайтовую запись в службы.
// SimpleBle

int main() {
    auto adapter_optional = Utils::getAdapter();

    if (!adapter_optional.has_value()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto adapter = adapter_optional.value();

    std::vector<SimpleBLE::Peripheral> peripherals;

....

 std::string contents;
    std::cout << "Please write the contents to be sent: ";
    std::cin >> contents;

    if (!selection.has_value()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    peripheral.write_request(uuids[selection.value()].first,  uuids[selection.value()].second, contents);

    peripheral.disconnect();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// blinc

void binc_characteristic_write(Characteristic *characteristic, const GByteArray *byteArray, WriteType writeType);


Значит ли это, что необходимо вначале скопировать весь аудиофайл в массив байтов? Если да, то каким образом это лучше сделать? Как обычно делают подобные приложения? Может быть я всё усложняю или не понял чего-то и мне следует что-то ещё почитать, в таком случае, пожалуйста укажите в каком направлении двигаться.

Копирование файла в массив байт - это в любом случае единственный способ получению доступа к его содержимому. Непонятно, что вас смущает.

@user7860670 mmap?

Если рассматривать вопрос с сугубо юзерской точки зрения, то задача "Колонка должна проигрывать музыку и по команде с монитора переключать её" решается любым медиаплеером с pulseaudio или pipewire, проблем с установкой которых на raspberry pi быть наверно не должно. Вы уверены, что вам тут нужен C++? Или я задачу неправильно понял?

@user7860670, да, наверное это не очень умная часть вопроса, просто мне казалось, что файл не должен передаваться целиком, а должен как-то постепенно читаться. Ведь если мы его передаем целиком - это может быть достаточно долго, ведь аудио-файлы достаточно большие, а музыка, например в bluetooth-наушниках подгружается практически мгновенно. Мне почему-то казалось, что передача должна осуществляться частями, наподобии udp..

@andreymal, в конечном итоге должно быть embedded устройство, я думаю сделать дистрибутив с использованием yocto и добавить часть с bluetooth к уже готовым частям проекта. Если у Вас есть предложения как это сделать иначе (например если бы pulseaudio можно управлять изнутри кода c++, тогда да, без проблем)

Побайтовая запись в службы не предполагает, что туда надо обязательно побайтово записывать файлы целиком. @andreymal mmap по сути тоже выполняет копирование файла в массив байт.
